# Export Hidden Column in DataTable to Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am new in javascript. I have used datatable like below in my PHP application. All is working fine. I have made some column hidden in table due to space issue. I want export all columns with excel. Currently its only exporting visible columns.

```
        <table class='table-striped' id='questions'
                                data-toggle="table"
                                data-url="get-list.php?table=question"
                                data-click-to-select="true"
                                data-side-pagination="server"
                                data-pagination="true"
                                data-page-list="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]"
                                data-search="true" data-show-columns="true"
                                data-show-refresh="true" data-trim-on-search="false"
                                data-sort-name="id" data-sort-order="desc"
                                data-mobile-responsive="true"
                                data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-show-export="true"
                                data-maintain-selected="true"
                                data-export-types='["txt","excel"]'
                                data-export-options='{
                                    "fileName": "questions-list-<?=date('d-m-y')?>",
                                    "ignoreColumn": ["state","IMAGE_FILE","operate"],



                                }'
                                data-query-params="queryParams_1"
                                >
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                                        <th data-field="ID" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
                                        <th data-field="R_DATE" data-sortable="true" data-visible='false'>R DATE</th>
                                        <th data-field="Q_NUM" data-sortable="true" data-visible='false'>Q NUM</th>
                                        <th data-field="HIDDEN_IMAGE" data-visible="false">IMAGE</th>
                                        <th data-field="IMAGE_FILE" data-sortable="false">Image</th>
                                        <th data-field="Q_TYPE" data-sortable="true">Q TYPE</th>
                                        <th data-field="SOURCE_TYPE" data-sortable="true">S TYPE</th>
                                        <th data-field="SOURCE" data-sortable="true">SOURCE</th>
                                        <th data-field="S_CAT" data-sortable="true">S CAT</th>
                                        <th data-field="CAT" data-sortable="true">CAT</th>

                                        <th data-field="QUESTION" data-sortable="true">Question</th>
                                        <th data-field="A1" data-sortable="true">A1</th>
                                        <th data-field="A2" data-sortable="true" data-visible='false'>A2</th>
                                        <th data-field="A3" data-sortable="true" data-visible='false'>A3</th>
                                        <th data-field="A4" data-sortable="true" data-visible='false'>A4</th>
                                        <th data-field="operate" data-sortable="true" data-events="actionEvents">Operate</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
```

I have tried lot of example and questions answers but none of them have solved my issue, Let me know if someone can help me for do it. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, but I can tell you that you shouldn't waste time asking this question on the Datatables site. They will simply close it without even replying, much less answering. There are tons of questions on that site where they've done that. If I find out how, I'll circle back with you here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the actual product called 'Datatables' somehow. If so, then you need to add something to your export:
exportOptions: {
**orthogonal: "dataExport"**
}
You're not showing your javascript, and I've never seen all these options done in HTML. Are you using some kind of framework, maybe Wordpress? I don't use WP so I can't help you on how to do this in that product. But just add 'orthogonal: "dataExport" ' to your 'data-export-options' thing. (you don't have to name it 'dataExport' -- I use that name because it's in some of the examples on the Datatables site).